# How to send a stream of data from a JS application to Lamda running on NodeJS and return concurrently

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a Angular JS application, from this application I send data to my AWS API endpoint

```
  /**
   * Bulk sync with master
   */

      async syncDataWithMaster(): Promise<AxiosResponse<any> | void> {
    {
          axios.defaults.headers.post.Authorization = token;
          const url = this.endpoint;
          return axios.post(url, compressed, {
            onUploadProgress: progressEvent => {
              console.log('uploading')
            },
            onDownloadProgress: progressEvent => {
              console.log('downloading')
            },
          }).then((response) => {
    
            if (response.data.status == 'success') {
    
              return response;
            } else {
              throw new Error('Could not authenticate user');
            }
          });
        } catch (e) {
        }
    
        return;
      }
```

the api gateway triggers my Lambda function (NodeJS) with the data it received:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {

    const localData = JSON.parse(event.body);


/**
Here get data from master and compare with local data and send back any new data 
**/


    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(newData),
    };
    return response;
};
```

the lambda function will call the database and get the master data for a user (not shown in the example)  and then this data is compare using various logic with the local data and it determines if we need to send any new rows back to the local device to be store/ updated. (Before anyone asks, the nature of the application needs full data)

This principle works great for 90% of my users. However some users have fairly large amounts of data the current maximum being around 17mb of data.

So my question is is it possible to stream the data to and from the lambda function? So stream the data to the function, process and stream back? So that it is not affected by payload limits from AWS?

Or is it possible to somehow, begin sending data to the function as a stream and then as data becomes available it starts streaming data back at the same time?

(Data is JSON format)

I am wondering what alternatives to this solution (as it need to be fairly  quick as well max 30sec)

(One other idea I had was for certain data above a certain size, frist client saves to s3 using signed url. The calls the api gateway for lambda. Lambda gets the saved file and compare to master. New data to be returned saved to s3 if over certain size. Then signed url returned to client. Client downloads the new data and processes) - However I am not sure if this of cost effective and it sounds live execution time may be long

Thanks for any help, been trying to figure this out for a while now

Comment: No, you cannot receive a 'stream' response from an AWS Lambda function, although the code in the function can of course 'send' data to a destination (eg S3) while still running. It is quite common to send an S3 URL to an AWS Lambda function and have the function retrieve the data from S3 for processing.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein thanks fro you answer. Is Lamda limited to the size of data it can send/ receive from S3?

Comment: There are no limits on the amount of data that can go in/out of an AWS Lambda function, however the default disk space in `/tmp/` is 512MB. You can increase that size (extra cost applies), or you can attach an Amazon EFS filesystem.